# uglyfy - I've combined all the js files. Now what?

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, minify

I started a small web/html project, in which I will have at least a few js files, including dependencies and stuff.

Just because I like it clean, I'd like to minify all those files into one. That's pretty easy with `uglifyjs` and `grunt`, problem solved.

But there's something else: in my "source" (uncompiled) html file, I have a bunch of `<script>` tags. Something like this:

```
<script src="js/dependency1.js"/>
<script src="js/dependency2.js"/>
<script src="js/mystuff.js"/>
```

But as I said above, after the build I end up with one big file, `allTheStuff.js`. I wish I could automatically modify my HTML to:

```
<script src="js/allMyStuff.js"/>
```

Is there a way I can do that automatically? Any tool to recommend?
And same question for CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) for this.  It will handle both javascript and CSS.

From the [GitHub page](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) for the project:

> Replaces references to non-optimized scripts or stylesheets into a set
>   of HTML files (or any templates/views).

When it works, it's a really nice tool to simplify the exact problem you describe.  The downside is that it's a little clunky to use as you juggle the HTML tags usemin needs and the grunt configuration.

But, clunky config issues aside, I've used it and it's very nice to automate the copy, concat, and uglify steps and to modify the HTML to use the results of those tasks.

***Related***: [grunt-include-source](https://github.com/jwvdiermen/grunt-include-source) offers automation to inject a list of files into your HTML. If you decided you wanted to handle things yourself rather than turn it all over to `usemin`, this tool is a handy item to automate updating the HTML as you build a custom build process based upon your needs.